# JHipster - Best practices for REST API

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jhipster

I'm trying to create a REST API using JHipster.

1. Is JHipster available for creating REST Api?
2. Should I create the paths and DTOs using Openapi (swagger) or with JHipster?
3. Is there an easier way to create REST Api with Spring Boot other than JHipster? (Includes advanced features such as Test, CI/CD, Cloud, Hibernate, Cache)

What I've tried so far:

I have created DTO and RequestMappings using Swagger but I have to struggle to map them to Entity. On the other hand, if I try to build using JHipster, it creates them all automatically, but I can't take advantage of Openapi. Which one do you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, JHipster can create REST APIs, that's one of its main features and it can do it using 2 approaches: code-first  and API-first.

Code-first is the default approach in JHipster and it generates the openapi/swagger specification and documentation from annotations.

API-first is the reverse, you build manually an openapi/swagger specification and generate code from it. However, the generated code is not complete and requires manual coding. See https://www.jhipster.tech/doing-api-first-development/

Code first is where JHipster will help you more.
Both approaches can be mixed in a JHipster application.